# Data Collector Component Name Doesn't Change After Updating SQL Server Name

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I cloned a SQL Server, and changed the name of the machine and SQL Server, but the old name continues to show up as a component name in the disk usage data collector, which I believe is what's causing that job to fail.

This is part of the error in the job history for that task that includes the old name:

```
SSIS error. Component name: TSQLQuery_OLD_NAME_MSSQL10_50_MSSQLSERVER_{}_1_Collect
```

I have already dropped the old name using `sp_dropserver` and added the new server name using `sp_addserver`. I verified that `SELECT SERVERPROPERTY('MachineName')` brings up the correct information, as does `sp_helpserver`. However, `SELECT @@SERVERNAME` brings up a NULL value, despite restarting the server.

How do I change the component name?

Comment: I think you need to include more details of the error.

Comment: As long as `@@SERVER` returns NULL, you did not apply the drop server/add server correctly. Do it again, make sure you follow [Rename a Computer that Hosts a Stand-Alone Instance of SQL Server](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143799.aspx).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I cloned an MS SQL server, and changed the name of the machine and SQL
>   server, but the old name continues to show up as a component name in
>   the disk usage data collector, which I believe is what's causing that
>   job to fail
>
> However, SELECT @@SERVERNAME brings up a NULL value, despite
>   restarting the server.
>
> How do I change the component name?

Give this a shot since you state `SELECT @@SERVERNAME` brings up a NULL value, despite restarting the server.

**1.** Run the below with the local as the second argument. . .

**TSQL**

```
SP_DROPSERVER
GO
SP_ADDSERVER 'NewServerName', local
GO
```

**2.** Restart SQL Server (if you can restart the server OS meaning power cycle it)

**3.** Run the below once it's back up and confirm . . .

**TSQL**

```
SELECT @@SERVERNAME 
SELECT SERVERPROPERTY('ServerName')
```

**4.** If the values are correct, then rerun your SSIS process and see if that resolves it as well.

---

### [SP_ADDSERVER](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174411.aspx)

> **[ @local = ] 'LOCAL'** Specifies that the server that is being added as a local server. @local is varchar(10), with a default of NULL.
>   Specifying @local as LOCAL defines @server as the name of the local
>   server and causes the @@SERVERNAME function to return the value of
>   server.
>
> SQL Server Setup sets this variable to the computer name during
>   installation. By default, the computer name is the way users connect
>   to an instance of SQL Server without requiring additional
>   configuration.
>
> The local definition takes effect only after the Database Engine is
>   restarted. Only one local server can be defined in each instance of
>   the Database Engine.